# Laravel api returning 401 (Authentication failed) even when logged in

Tags: vue.js, laravel-6, http-status-code-401, laravel-api

i have created a simple crud app using Laravel 6 and VueJs it was working fine before but when i added middleware **auth** to api routes group it returns **error 401** even when logged in.

here is **api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','auth']], function(){


    Route::get('contacts',function(){
        return Contact::latest()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    });

    Route::get('contact/{id}',function($id){
        return Contact::findOrFail($id);
    });

    Route::post('contact/store',function(Request $request){

        return Contact::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone
        ]);

    });

    Route::patch('contact/{id}',function(Request $request, $id){

        $contact =  Contact::findOrFail($id);

        $contact->name =  $request->name;
        $contact->email  =  $request->email;
        $contact->phone = $request->phone;
        $contact->save();


        return $contact;

    });

    Route::delete('contact/{id}',function($id){
        return Contact::destroy($id);
    });



});
```

Comment: do you send the `api_token` with your request?

Comment: try to edit `'middleware' => ['api','auth']` to `'middleware' => ['auth:api']`

Comment: no i am not sending any api_token.

Comment: still not working after changing to `'middleware' => ['auth:api']`

Comment: you need to send `api_token` that's why you add auth middleware

Comment: read this part of [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests)